# Azure Stream Analytics query with multiple inputs

Tags: sql, azure, stream, analytics

## Issue

I have a Azure IoT-Hub sending messages to a Azure Stream Analytics Job.

Each message contains a 'NodeName'.
I have a table 'plcnext_nodes' which has a unique 'NodeId' for each node with their corresponding 'NodeName'.

How can I use both the input from the 'plcnext_nodes' table and the IoT-Hub messages to store the event data in another SQL table using the 'NodeId'?

I want to use the 'NodeId' instead of the 'NodeName' because some names can get very long and saving them over and over with each message is a waste of storage.

---

## Desired solution

I would like to parse the following **message from the IoT Hub**:

```
{
    "NodeName": "ns=5;s=Arp.Plc.Eclr/DI2",
    "NodeDataType": "Boolean",
    "EventValue": 0,
    "EventMeasuredUtcTime": "2019-11-11T12:15:22.4830000Z",
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2019-11-11T12:41:57.1706596Z",
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2019-11-11T12:15:32.1260000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Compare the 'NodeName' with those in the **plcnext_nodes** table to get the appropriate 'NodeId':

```
NodeId  NodeName                 NodeDataType
---------------------------------------------
1       ns=5;s=Arp.Plc.Eclr/DI1  Boolean
2       ns=5;s=Arp.Plc.Eclr/DI2  Boolean
...
```

To get the following output and insert into the **plcnext_events** table:

```
NodeId  EventValue  EventMeasured
-----------------------------------------------
1       0           2019-11-11 12:15:22.4830000
```

---

## Query

I have tried the following query on Azure Stream Analytics:

```
SELECT
    NodeId,
    EventValue,
    EventMeasuredUtcTime,
    EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
    EventProcessedUtcTime
INTO
    [plcnext_events]
FROM
    [plcnext_nodes],
    [iot_hub]
WHERE
    [iot_hub].NodeName = [plcnext-nodes].NodeName
```

But JOIN is not supported in FROM and I haven't been able to use a JOIN clause because of it's DATEDIFF restriction (The plcnext_nodes table has no timestamps)

#### Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Reference Data JOIN in Stream Analytics to join tables.

[Using Reference Data for Lookups in Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data)

> Reference data (also known as a lookup table) is a finite data set that is static or slowly changing in nature, used to perform a lookup or to augment your data streams.

In your case, go under the **Inputs** section in your Stream Analytics job and add a Reference Input. You can select either *Blob Storage* or *SQL Database* as your source.
[image: Add Reference Input]

You can then define your SQL query to return the reference data you need. For your case, your reference data query would look like this:

```
SELECT NodeId, NodeName, NodeDataType
FROM dbo.plcnext-nodes
```

Once you define your reference data join in SA, go to the **Query** section in Stream Analytics and update your query. For your scenario your query would look like this (with the JOIN):

```
SELECT
   pn.NodeId,
   hub.EventValue,
   hub.EventMeasuredUtcTime,
   hub.EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
   hub.EventProcessedUtcTime
   INTO [plcnext_events]
FROM [iot_hub] hub
JOIN [plcnext-nodes] pn ON pn.NodeName = hub.NodeName
```

Comment: Thanks! worked a treat. Had not thought about adding it as a reference table ;)